# Draw a MapsApp-like Overlay

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I'm stuck with an task, that seem's to me not so trivial as i though before.
I need to make an app which uses MapActivity, and draw some overlays on it... (that's done),
now I have a problem with the onTap() method, I need to make it look like in the original 
Maps App for Android, Like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkZEr.png

I'm new to android, and it seems there's no tutorial which could explain how to
write classes for such overlays...

Answer (score 2):

```
in onTap()

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylocation_balloon, null);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,mapOverlays.get(index).getPoint(), 0, -70, LayoutParams.MODE_MAP | LayoutParams.CENTER);
```